# Combine (add) value from 2 different hashtable together

Tags: powershell

I was tasked with created a script to pull DHCP stats from a couple of particular scopes. I was able to get the stats no problem, however the output returned 2 results from the same scope. The problem is, whoever created this scope, created 2 identical scopes on 2 different servers but set the unusable address flipped in order to create "round robin"

I.e.

```
Server 1 has scope 10.10.92.0/23 (255.255.254.0)
    10.10.92.48 as start of addresses
    10.10.93.249 as end of addresses
    10.10.93.1 to 10.10.93.249 IP **EXCLUSION**

Server 2 has scope 10.10.92.0/23 (255.255.254.0)
    10.10.92.48 as start of addresses
    10.10.93.249 as end of addresses
    10.10.92.48 to 10.10.92.255 IP **EXCLUSION**
```

So my output in the HTML file would show:

[1st result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2werF.png)
[2nd result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2Oxt.png)

I redid my code and I manage to separate the results into hashtables, but now I want to combine the results and then generate a new html file based on that. The below code works but all attempts to try and combine the results resulted in failure or syntax error. Looking for a little guidance here.

```
$hashtable1 = @{} #create hash table
$scopes1 = Get-DhcpServerv4Scope -ComputerName NAMEOFSERVER | Select-Object ScopeId, SubnetMask, StartRange, EndRange, LeaseDuration, State | Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.ScopeId -like "10.10*" } #get all scopes
foreach ($scope in $scopes1) { $stats1 = Get-DhcpServerv4ScopeStatistics -ComputerName covdhcp5 -ScopeId $scope.scopeid.IPAddressToString | select Free, InUse, Reserved, percentageInUse
    $array1 = @()
    foreach ($var1 in $stats1) { $array1 += $var1 }
    $hashtable1.add($scope.scopeid.IPAddressToString, $array1)}

$hashtable2 = @{} #create hash table
$scopes2 = Get-DhcpServerv4Scope -ComputerName NAMEOFSERVER | Select-Object ScopeId, SubnetMask, StartRange, EndRange, LeaseDuration, State | Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.ScopeId -like "10.10*" } #get all scopes
foreach ($scope in $scopes2) { $stats2 = Get-DhcpServerv4ScopeStatistics -ComputerName covdhcp6 -ScopeId $scope.scopeid.IPAddressToString | select Free, InUse, Reserved, percentageInUse
    $array2 = @()
    foreach ($var2 in $stats2) { $array2 += $var2 }
    $hashtable2.add($scope.scopeid.IPAddressToString, $array2)}
```

Comment: It is very confusing what you are trying to do here.  What results do you want to combine exactly?  $hashtable1 and $hashtable2?  The results that are in $array1 and/or $array2?  What exactly are you trying to accomplish?  There is probably a much easier way then all these arrays and hashtables that are flying around.

Comment: Yes both, because I want to manipulate each value. If it was just one DHCP, I wouldn't need to do it this way.